# On the definition of a smooth function on an arbitrary set

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-topology

Suppose that $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is arbitrary, and $f :A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Then $f$ is defined as smooth as long as for each point $x \in A$, there exists an open set $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ containing $x$ and a smooth function $g:U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ which agrees with $f$ on $A$.

Now, I always assumed that the extending function did not matter, so that if $g$ and $g'$ are two smooth extensions as described above, then we are okay in just defining, for each component $i$,
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}(x)=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_{i}}(x)=\frac{\partial g'}{\partial x_{i}}(x) $$

After further thought, this obviously is not the case. Consider the set $A=\{0\}$, and define the function $f :A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as $f(0)=0$. Then by definition, both $g(x)=x^{2}$ and $g'(x)=x$ are smooth extensions of $f$, which produce different derivatives at $x=0$.

What must we then have to ensure that the choice of extension does not matter? Do we need that the interior of $A$ be non-empty in order to exploit the continuity of derivatives?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the classical way is to consider the germ of $f$. So this means that it is well defined as soon as you have an open neighborhood. The idea of germ enables to say that the 'size' of the open subset doesn't matter as soon as it is non empty.

Answer (score 5):

Having nonempty interior is not enough. For example, if $A\subseteq \mathbb R^2$ is the union of the closed left half-plane and the $x$-axis, then at points of the positive $x$-axis, the $y$-derivatives are not determined by the function's values on $A$.

What you need is for the set $A$ to be contained in the closure of its interior. If that's the case, then for each point $p\in A$, there is a sequence of points $p_i\in \operatorname{Int} A$ such that $p_i\to p$. If $f\colon A\to \mathbb R$ is a function and $g$ is any smooth extension of $f$ to a neighborhood of $p$, then any partial derivative $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x^j}(p)$ is equal to a limit of partial derivatives of $f$ at the points $p_i$, and thus is completely determined by $f$.